# "incompatible type in initializtion"

Tags: objective-c, double

my caller-code looks like this:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"a", A_KEY,
      @"b", B_KEY, 
      @"x", X_KEY,
      nil];
id exp = [[self brain] expression];

double result = [[self brain] evaluateExpression:exp
    usingVariableValues:myDictionary]; -> this is the error line
```

- expression is defined as: `@property (readonly) id expression;` (i do not think that's relevant)

the signature of the function "evaluateExpression:exp..." is:

```
" + (double)evaluateExpression:(id)anExpression
usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variables;"
```

The error i am receiving:
`"incompatible type in initializtion"`

I can't figure this one out - it's simply initializing a double variable with a method which returns a double. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing this question should be tagged objective-c instead of go.

Comment: how are `A_KEY` et al defined?

Comment: where are you defining A_KEY,B_KEY,X_KEY,

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the plus at the beginning of the method declaration to a minus. A plus indicates a class method, and you're (as far as I can tell) calling it against an instance.

I think the above mistake is causing the compiler to not know that the method is returning a double, hence the error.

Comment: THat was it - forgot my methos was a class mathod, therfore calling it must not be through an object instance...